# The smallest number that can be discribed as a sum of three squares in two different ways with equal multiple.

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

> What is the smallest number $k$ that is a sum of three squares in two different ways(there does not exist a pair of numbers from different triple which are the same)
> $$a_0^2+b_0^2+c_0^2=a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2=k$$
> Such that $a_0b_0c_0=a_1b_1c_1$?
> Also, does there exist a solution in two numbers?
> Note: All the numbers mentioned are non-zero natural numbers

My Attempt:
I’ve started with the two variable case as it seemed easier, and I got to the equation:
$$a_0^2k-a_0^4=a_1^2k-a_1^4$$
Needing to have two solutions where $a$ and $b$ are distinct for some fixed $k$.
It looks like it implies no solutions but I had not managed to prove it.
I’ve also tried parity arguments to no success.
I've found a pair of triples, $1^2+12^2+10^2=2^2+4^2+15^2 = 245$ and $1\cdot 12 \cdot 10 = 2\cdot 4\cdot 15=120$ but I'm unsure of it's minimality.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a similar kind of question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373582/are-sum-product-n-triplets-unique-and-hard-to-solve

Comment: Ah, Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I ran a program to find all sums that you seek and copied the results of sums up to 245 into a spreadsheet. From there, I used a multiply formula on all triples. I found no 'k' lower than 245 so I think you have found the smallest.

Comment: For the two variable analogue, it’s easy to see that $x^2+y^2$ and $xy$ together determine $(x+y)^2$ and $(x-y)^2$, hence also $x+y$ and $|x-y|$, hence the set $\{x,y\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triples under $99$ (excluding equal product considerations) include

\begin{align*}
1^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 = 2^2 + 2^2 + 5^2 = 33\\
1^2 + 1^2 + 6^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 = 38\\
1^2 + 2^2 + 6^2 = 3^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 = 41\\
1^2 + 2^2 + 7^2 = 2^2 + 5^2 + 5^2 = 3^2 + 3^2 + 6^2 = 54\\
1^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 7^2 = 62\\
1^2 + 1^2 + 8^2 = 1^2 + 4^2 + 7^2 = 66\\
1^2 + 2^2 + 8^2 = 2^2 + 4^2 + 7^2 = 69\\
1^2 + 3^2 + 8^2 = 3^2 + 4^2 + 7^2 = 74\\
2^2 + 3^2 + 8^2 = 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 = 77\\
1^2 + 4^2 + 8^2 = 3^2 + 6^2 + 6^2 = 81\\
1^2 + 1^2 + 9^2 = 3^2 + 5^2 + 7^2 = 83\\
1^2 + 2^2 + 9^2 = 1^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 = 5^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 = 86\\
2^2 + 2^2 + 9^2 = 2^2 + 7^2 + 6^2 = 3^2 + 4^2 + 8^2 = 89\\
1^2 + 5^2 + 8^2 = 4^2 + 5^2 + 7^2 = 90\\
2^2 + 3^2 + 9^2 = 3^2 + 2^2 + 9^2 = 3^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 = 94\\
1^2 + 4^2 + 9^2 = 3^2 + 5^2 + 8^2 = 98\\
1^2 + 7^2 + 7^2 = 3^2 + 3^2 + 9^2 = 5^2 + 5^2 + 7^2 = 99\\
\end{align*}
I put these and all others up to 245 in a spreadsheet with product formulas for each triple. Only those for the sum 245 had more than one triple with the same product.